# Not hitting javascript breakpoints

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer-9, breakpoints

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I HAVE NOW REBUILT MY MACHINE TO REMOVE THIS BUG, SO I CANNOT ANY LONGER VERIFY ANY ANSWERS.**

I'm experiencing a problem when attempting to debug javascript using Visual Studio 2008. I've recently installed IE9, but that may not be the cause.

My javascript is in its own separate (.js) file, but whenever I put a breakpoint on a line, it just becomes hollow and says it will not be hit. Then sure enough, it isn't.

I've been into the IE internet options>advanced menu and unchecked the following:

> disable script debugging (IE)
>
> disable script debugging (Other)

I've also rebooted my PC. But still the breakpoints are not hit.

**Edit**: I've just noticed that there are two iexplore.exe entries in the "attach to process" window. That's surely not right! But how do I fix it.

[image]

**Update**:

Other things I've now tried:

- Uninstalling IE9 and using IE8 instead.
- Unchecking "enable third-party browser extensions" in IE tools>options menu

Comment: this might help - http://geekswithblogs.net/geekrutherford/archive/2011/10/14/why-isnt-visual-studio-letting-me-debug-javascript-any-longer.aspx , http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsdebug/thread/c3957b15-4f8a-4a6a-ba11-e2a5cdd1125d

Comment: Also, whether client debug is working? (for IE use shortcut F12)

Comment: @Sandeep The first link doesn't apply as I don't have Silverlight installed, and the second link doesn't have any actual answers. It appears client debug does not work- I get the following error when I try to start debugging `Unable to attach to the process. Another debugger might be attached to the process.`

Comment: Just noticed my "script documents" are not appearing at all when I run in VS2008.

Comment: Are you able to even try loading the page using a different browser?  If so, does it by any chance let you set a breakpoint there?  Can you set a breakpoint on another js file within this project?

Comment: Yes, it seems to debug ok in firefox and Chrome. It's not a solution for me though, because I need to be using IE.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the javascript key word "debugger;" in the line you want to set the breakpoint. It never fails me. =P

Comment: I think Leandro is right . Using "debugger" you can handle breakpoints in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling third-party browser extensions as per [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/iewebdevelopment/thread/645cbacc-333a-46cc-972a-6a2a1749e8fa).

In IE, go to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced and uncheck `Enable third-party browser extensions (requires restart)`.

Make sure you restart IE.

Answer (score 0):

Well IE has a debugger turned off by default, so try to hit F12 and go to "Script" tab and click "Start Debugging" which will turn the brakepoins on
And the 
`debugger;` 
will work only in the "debugging" mode

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but try this

http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/06/01/VS-Debug-Problem-with-IE8.aspx

It worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

**Use a proper browser**

I do most of my javascript dev in Firefox with [Firebug plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and Chrome with [developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) (F12).

Firebug particularly is awesome for stepping through code, once you've tried it you wont ever want to use anything else.

You can use Firefox/Firebug in combination with Visual Studio, while this will not let you debug inside your IDE the alternative of using IE is pretty unreliable. You can then debug your JavaScript easily inside the Firefox Browser which provides much better step-by-step debugging support and colour coding for easily identifying javascript objects (arrays, strings, dates, numbers etc).

[image]

Comment: -1: To help someone solve a very understandable problem by dictating that they use a different product is not right.  They want to be able to debug using visual studio.  If you can't help with that, don't bother answering the question.

Comment: Agreed. Firefox is no use to me in this case anyway, since my software is only designed for use in IE. But probably worth mentioning that Firefox does work, and doesn't give this problem.

Comment: VERY UNDERTSTANDABLE? How is c**p software that doesnt work understandable? Shoot me down for suggesting a tool that actually works!

Comment: A careful re-reading will show that Gabriel was suggesting that the *problem* is very understandable - which it is.

Comment: And as I said, the solution is to use a tool that does the job. VisualStudio / Firebug combo is far better for debugging than VS/IE (ie. it actually works).